# Liquibase conditional migration

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, liquibase

I want to automate some migration processes for stack: Java, Maven, Spring-Boot, Postgres, Liquibase.

Is it possible to postpone some liquibase change logs until a specific maven module version?

Example:

- changes:

  - changelog1.yaml
  - changelog2.yaml
- 2.1: # Executed during deployment of version 2.1

  - changelog3.yaml
  - changelog4.yaml
- 2.2: # Executed during deployment of version 2.2

  - changelog5.yaml
  - changelog6.yaml

In the case of deployment 2.0, only the first 2 change logs will be applied.

Any idea how to do it?

Comment: there is a mechanism of contexts: https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/advanced/contexts.html. But it looks like you're doing it wrong with organizing the coding process in general. You can create git tags, for example, and deploy the tag you want, which will contain only needed changes.

Comment: Suppose I need to rename some column from a to b. I will create a new column b from a and redeploy all pods (application instances), during redeployment old and new pods can work together. With the next release, I will remove column a. Do you have some cons, comments, or ideas?

Comment: I understand the problem is all the versions already exist? If you're maintaining all three versions in separate branches, I'd commit each changelog to the branch corresponding to the version for which it should first be introduced, then probably cherry-pick the commit to all successive branches. Also, normally you would bump 2.1 to 3.0 since removing a column is not backwards compatible

Comment: This approach requires developer action. I need to automate this process. I want deployment without actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Liquibase Labels allow you to choose a subset of changesets to execute at the runtime.

Labels can be specified using AND, OR, !, and () (parentheses that are used for grouping). For example:

```
labels="!v.2.1"
labels="v.2.0 and v.2.1"
labels="v.2.0 or v.2.1"
labels="!v.2.0 and !v.2.1"
```

Where the version could be the maven module version in your case.